# Detail Page using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to create a detail page, but when I click button `examp_title`, I can't move to Tryout/soal.

Thank You

Controller (Tryout.php)

```
public function deskripsi($tryout_id)
{
    $data['tryout'] = $this->M_tryout->deskripsi_to($tryout_id)->row();
    $data['exam_tpa'] = $this->M_tryout->get_exam_tpa($tryout_id)->result();
    $data['exam_tps'] = $this->M_tryout->get_exam_tps($tryout_id)->result();
    $this->load->view('tryout/deskripsi', $data);
}


public function soal($exam_code)
{
    $data['soal'] = $this->M_tryout->get_soal_tryout($exam_code)->result;
    $this->load->view('tryout/soal', $data);
}
```

View (deskripsi.php)

```
<?php foreach ($exam_tps as $key => $value) { ?>

     <h5 class="fw-bold" class="sub_to">
         <a href="<?php base_url('tryout/soal/') ?> 
             <?php echo $exam->exam_code?>">
             <?php echo $value->exam_title;?>
         </a>
     </h5>
            
     <p>
         <?php echo $value->exam_duration;?> Menit, 
         <?php echo $value->exam_count_question;?> soal <br> Pembahasan
     </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The First thing to do would be to inspect the generated HTML in your Browser using View Source and check the generated code. Does it make sense? Also can you directly access the controller/method/value via the URL. What errors are you getting/

Comment: when I click the link button it always redirects to  base_url/deskripsi/exam_code even though  i write base_url/soal/exam_code

Comment: Can you provide the section of HTML that is generated?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p1AjwquoSQLjeFvdTJh9g6kciFSon24Z/view?usp=sharing
This is the result of the view code section above

Comment: you should use `echo` between `<?php echo base_url('tryout/soal/')?>`

Comment: @Novanda your problem is solved by `echo`?

Comment: @KUMAR yes, its solved by echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `<a>` tag is not outputting the link you want due to a missing `echo`.
I have simplified the `href` below...

```
<h5 class="fw-bold" class="sub_to">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('tryout/soal/') . $exam->exam_code ?>">
        <?php echo $value->exam_title; ?>
    </a>
</h5>
```